# Gatling script compilation error saying value 'check' is not a member

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have a method in a gatling user-script as below.
This script was written in gatling 2.3.

```
def registerAddress: ChainBuilder = {
    exec(ws("WS Register Address").wsName(id)
      .sendText(prefetchAddress)
      .check(wsAwait.within(30).until(1).regex("success").exists))
      .exec(ping)
}
```

I am converting this in to gatling 3.0 and when I try to run it I get the following error.

```
value check is not a member of io.gatling.http.action.ws.WsSendTextFrameBuilder
```

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find a documentation related to `WsSendTextFrameBuilder` class to change the method call accordingly.

Does anyone know a documentation related to this class or a way to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation of Gatling 2.3 and 3.0 I found the new calls for the above scenario.

Apparently the `check` method is not available anymore in the `WsSendTextFrameBuilder` class.
Instead of that should use the `await` method.

So the code would look something similar to below.

```
val checkReply = ws.checkTextMessage("request").check(regex("request-complete"))
def registerAddress: ChainBuilder = {
    exec(ws("WS Register Address").wsName(id)
      .sendText(prefetchAddress)
      .await(30 seconds)(checkReply))
      .exec(ping)
}
```